# Is it normal to have a full Silverlight website?

Tags: silverlight, ria

Is it okay to have a full silverlight website? I've seen some website implements a full Flash website.

If yes, how can i separate pages, so they load only when user clicks on a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would only use this approach if you want to force your potential users to have the sliverlight plugin.  So, on a site that is open to the internet at large, I would say no.  You are just alienating some potential users/viewers by forcing them to have the plugin.

Comment: well, i was thinking of creating multidomain website. Any idea how i can separate pages instead of putting them in one xap?